# How to hide field title if field is empty/blank?

Tags: php

Can anyone help me with this...
I'm kind a new in php coding so I don't know  how to do this...
How can I make the field title,  If field is left empty or blank?
In my case it is the video field and the gallery field.

```
    <?php  } ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php
            do_action( 'et_before_content' );
            echo '<div class="video-img">';
            echo '</br><span class="video">Video</span>' . types_render_field("video", array("show_name" => false));
            echo '</br><span class="gallery">Gallery</span>' . types_render_field("gallery", array("show_name" => false));
            echo '</div>';
        ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: wich framework are you using?

Comment: im using wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Store the field inside a variable, then check if the variable is not empty before echoing it.

```
<?php do_action( 'et_before_content' ); ?>

<div class="video-img">    

<?php $video = types_render_field("video", array("show_name" => false));
      if( $video !== "" ){ ?>
        </br><span class="video">Video</span><?=$video?> 
<?php } ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just made some twitching with your answer and got it working... thanks alot

```
    $video = types_render_field("video", array("show_name" => false));
          if( $video !== "" ){ 
            echo '</br><span class="video">Video</span>' . $video;
     }
```